# R - How to convert a categorical variable in frequencies

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I need to make with the categorical variables a new variable that takes the frequency of each category. I've written the following code:

```
df[ , t_Product := .N , by = .(Product)]
```

but I have this error:

```
 Error in `[.data.frame`(datos, , `:=`(t_Product, .N), by = .(Product)) : 
  unused argument (by = .(Product))
```

where `df` is my dataframe, `t_Product` is the name of the new column and `Product` is the current column.

If I am right I am grouping by the column `Product` and creating an other column named `t_Product` that take count, so takes the frequency...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your data in `data.table` format? It is not, but just so you know how to test if it is in the future, run the following line of code:

```
is.data.table(df)
```

It should output `FALSE`

In order to counteract this, add the following before your code:

```
library(data.table) #import data.table package

df = as.data.table(df) #convert df to data.table

df[, t_Product := .N , by = .(Product)] #your code
```

OR

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, t_Product := .N , by = .(Product)]
```

**Example with Palmer Penguins**

```r
library(data.table)
library(palmerpenguins)
data(package = 'palmerpenguins') #importing the palmer penguins data

df = as.data.table(penguins) #you can also use setDT(df)
df[, t_Product := .N , by = .(species)] #using your code here
df[, .(species, island, t_Product)] #selecting columns using column name

#>        species    island t_Product
#>   1:    Adelie Torgersen       152
#>   2:    Adelie Torgersen       152
#>   3:    Adelie Torgersen       152
#>   4:    Adelie Torgersen       152
#>   5:    Adelie Torgersen       152
#>  ---                              
#> 340: Chinstrap     Dream        68
#> 341: Chinstrap     Dream        68
#> 342: Chinstrap     Dream        68
#> 343: Chinstrap     Dream        68
#> 344: Chinstrap     Dream        68
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you use will be recognized by an object of class `data.table` but not an object of class `data.frame`.

I would then suggest to install the `data.table` package (if not already done) and add the following before your code line :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```